# Who manages the threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, low-latency

I would like to know who manages the threads created by the JVM in Java?

Comment: What do you mean ? Your question is absolutely not clear. The JVM manages the thread your program creates.

Comment: Is this answer sufficient? "JVM using the OS APIs".. if not what more are you looking for?

Comment: (Of course, the *real* answer is that it is an invisible green monkey whose name is George.  :-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The host operating system handles thread scheduling, preemption and the like in all recent HotSpot JVMs.  The JVM only takes a direct hand in the decision to create and delete threads, and in the related area of synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

JVM manages the thread on host operating system. and OS manages the JVM. Read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-07/04-qa-jvmthreads.html) about the JVM thread behavior

Comment: That is a HORRIBLY out of date article that you've linked to.  For a start, Sun / Oracle JVM's haven't supported green threads for a very long time.